# Variability in the line spacing of paragraph breaks?

Tags: compiling, koma-script, line-spacing

Don't know how to describe my problem properly, but there seems to be a variablility in the line spacing of paragraph breaks, with my settings or generally or anything. Since I don't know what is effecting this, I copied just some lines of the preamble, which might have some relevance to the problem and two screenshots, where you can see, what I mean.

```
\documentclass[paper=15cm:23cm, headinclude=true, draft]{scrbook}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8.0pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9.7pt}{10.5pt}\selectfont}

\areaset[10mm]{112mm}{194mm}
```

The spaces between the Paragraph are slightly different.. Why?
I also get the message:

```
Package typearea Warning: Maybe no optimal type area settings! 
                          The maximum limit of line width is about 16%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically detected line width.
(typearea)                You may e.g. increase DIV, decrease fontsize
(typearea)                or change the papersize.
```

I would like to get a consistent spacing, which seems for me more in the right way, than an inconsistent one. I also never saw this in books (academic publishing).

[image: Example one]
[image: Example two]

Comment: The difference between the baselines of each line inside a paragraph is given by the length `\baselineskip`, while an additional `\parskip` is added between paragraphs. Do you just want an explanation of these, or do you want to have a consistent spacing?

Comment: What probably happens is that in your setup the page doesn't contain an integer number of lines. So when there's no possibility to stretch spaces (which happens if you have a list or a section title, for example), the interparagraph space is the only one that can be stretched in order to fill the page.

Comment: @Werner I would like to get a consistent spacing, which seems for me more beautiful, than an inconsistent one. I also never saw this in books (academic publishing)..

Comment: Please have a look at the option `fontsize` of the documentation (use scrguide instead of scrguien, the German documentation is better.)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You mean like `\setparsizes{1.5em}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}`?

Comment: @algomachine: I mean: `\documentclass[fontsize=10dd]{scrbook}`

Comment: @algomachine: You could try `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`, but that may cause other warnings to creep up if your page layout isn't optimal. The glue allows some flexibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The distance between baselines within a paragraph is given by the length `\baselineskip`. So, in your definition of `\normalsize`, you use

```
\fontsize{9.7pt}{10.5pt}\selectfont
```

which sets `\baselineskip=10.5pt`. That is, the baselines in your paragraph will be `10.5pt` apart. Note that this is a property of a paragraph, and not of a line (see [Only one \baselineskip per paragraph](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-baselinepar)).

The distance between paragraphs is further extended by the length `\parskip`, which contains glue. This glue allows the paragraphs to stretch further apart or shrink closer depending on the amount of content (given by `0.0pt plus 1.0pt` in your case, allowing for `1pt` of stretch). So, you may see that the space between paragraphs (given by `\parskip`) differs from one page to the next. This is perfectly normal to obtain an optimal layout.

Specific to the KOMA-script classes, the [KOMA-script documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) (section **3.1.3 Options for Document Layout**, p 45) mentions:

> The standard classes normally set paragraphs indented and without any
> vertical inter-paragraph space. This is the best solution when using a
> regular page layout, like the ones produced with the [`typearea`
> package](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea). [...] A combination of indentation and vertical
> inter-paragraph spacing is redundant and therefore should be avoided.
> The indentation is perfectly sufficient by itself. The only drawback
> of indentation is the reduction of the line length. The use of
> inter-paragraph spacing is therefore justified when using short lines,
> for instance in a newspaper.